# iPhone simulator not responding when using storyboards

Tags: xcode, xcode4, uibutton, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

I'm quite new to iOS Programming. I've done Objective-C for about a year, and now I want to start making apps for the iPhone. I think I'm missing out on something really simple, though. What I've done is this:

First I created a new *Single View Application* with TestApp as a product name. I enabled *Use Storyboards*, Use *Automatic Reference Counting* and *Include Unit Tests*. After creating the project, I dragged a UIButton onto the View in the storyboard file.

**Note that I didn't write a single line of code.** I launched my app in the iPhone Simulator and pressed the button, but it's not responding. I know I didn't assign an action to the press of the button, but the gradient of the button isn't changing, as I know it should. The *User Interaction Enabled* properties of both my view and my button were enabled.

Recently, I've created a few apps in Xcode that worked just fine, but I didn't use storyboards in those projects. Thus, I'm guessing there's something extra to do when using storyboards of which I'm just unaware. I'm using Xcode 4.5 and the iPhone 6.0 Simulator.

I wrote `NSLog(@"View was loaded.");` statement in the `viewDidLoad` method of my ViewController to make sure this view controller was actually loaded. (I know my button wouldn't show up if it was the wrong view controller, but I did this just to make sure.)

I also wrote a changeTitle: method in my ViewController to change the title of my button to *New Title* after it was pressed, just in case the button worked but its gradient just wouldn't respond to a tap. I linked this `IBAction` to my button, but it wasn't called.

In my ViewController, I created an IBOutlet of a UIButton which I connected to my button. In the `viewDidLoad` method of my ViewController, I changed the title of my button to *New Title*, this actually worked. The title of my button changed to this new title when launching my app in the iOS Simulator. The button itself still wasn't responding, though.

As a last try, I also wrote `[button setEnabled:YES];` in my ViewController's `viewDidLoad` method, but this didn't help. My button still doesn't respond to any tap. What am I missing out on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird. I had an issue with my printer, so I restarted my computer. After this, this issue was suddenly solved as well (just like my printer issue). I'm not sure how this could have affected anything, but I'm glad it works again!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue.
Apparently Content Reseting the Simulator worked for me
Very strange this..